# What are the sandals worn with a kimono called?

Tags: word-requests

What is the term for sandals that are only worn with a kimono on special occasions?

Comment: Have you really tried to look for the answer for yourself? I can hardly believe you did your own research for this matter. For example [this page](http://blog.fromjapan.co.jp/en/fashion/japanese-sandals-what-you-need-to-know-about-geta-zori.html) is on the first page if you take time to google with `kimono sandal`.

Comment: @naruto, I search the site and jisho.org prior to asking questions on the site. Your answers have always provided me with exceptional detail and insight and I will incorporate these sites into my research. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then could you at least provide us with what you have gotten so far? I doubt you can get a long and through answer better than what is already on the net (especially Wikipedia) regarding a question like this. If you still have a question after actually spending a considerable amount of time regarding this matter, feel free to ask here, but don't forget to summarize your research effort you have already made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shoes are called Geta.. They are worn with the tabi socks , never bare footed. The shoes resemble plat form zori's but are not rubber. Some are very fancy other's rather plain , I'm sure as to not clash with the kimono. Fancy ones can be made out of the same material of the kimono. Childrens Geta's sometimes  have bell's that dangle in the plat form of the shoe.

Comment: `never bare footed` <- 下駄って裸足で履きますけど。特に浴衣の時。`same material of the kimono` <- 下駄って木製だと思っていましたが。。？ 草履の話ですかね？